# cambiar clases de div segun horario

Tags: javascript, script

Buenas necesito un script que cambie la clase de un div según el horario;
tengo ya este codigo que cambia la imagen segun la hora pero necesitaría añadir que cambie la clase del div con id="day_nd_night"

```js
<script>
function cargarImagen(){
ahora=new Date();
hora=ahora.getHours();
if(hora<8){
imagen="primera.jpg";
}

if(hora>7 && hora<12){
imagen="segunda.jpg";
estilos="mañana";
}
if(hora>11 && hora<18){
imagen="tercera.jpg";
estilos="tarde";
}
if(hora>17 && hora<24){
imagen="cuarta.jpg";
estilos="noche";
}
document.images["reloj"].src=imagen;
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body onload="cargarImagen()">

<div id="day_nd_night" class="clase a cambiar">
<img src="primera.jpg" name="reloj">
</div>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: puedes usar algo como esto: document.getElementById("mi_id").classList.add('MyClass');

document.getElementById("mi_id").classList.remove('MyClass');

Answer (score 0):

La forma más general de hacerlo es con:

```
document.getElementById("day_nd_night").className = "Class";
```

por lo que el script podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
function cargarImagen(){
ahora=new Date();
hora=ahora.getHours();
if(hora<8){
imagen="primera.jpg";
newClassForDiv = "ClassName";
}

if(hora>7 && hora<12){
imagen="segunda.jpg";
estilos="mañana";
newClassForDiv = "ClassName";
}
if(hora>11 && hora<18){
imagen="tercera.jpg";
estilos="tarde";
newClassForDiv = "ClassName";
}
if(hora>17 && hora<24){
imagen="cuarta.jpg";
estilos="noche";
newClassForDiv = "ClassName";
}
document.images["reloj"].src=imagen;
document.getElementById("day_nd_night").className = newClassForDiv;
}
```